# Пользовательские действия на клавишу PrintScreen

Tags: delphi, c++

Как реализовать, чтобы когда я нажимал клавишу PrintScreen, программа бы выполняла какое-либо действие?

P.S. И еще, можно ли это сделать так, чтобы даже если программа была свернута, то она все равно реагировала бы на нажатие кнопки принтскрин?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно написать в обработчике таймера такой код:

```
SrcKey:=GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SNAPSHOT);
If (SrcKey<>OldSrcKey) Then
  Begin

    // здесь написать обработчик на это действие
    OldSrcKey:=SrcKey;
  End;
```

А на обработчике FormCreate написать строку:

```
OldSrcKey:=GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SNAPSHOT);
```

Заранее подключить модуль Windows (если он не подключен) и объявить глобальные переменные:

```
OldSrcKey, SrcKey: SmallInt;
```

Если идея с таймером не нравится, то можно написать прогу вообще без формы, т. е. так, чтобы в фоновом режиме это действие обрабатывала.

Answer (score 0):

В обработчике главной формы OnCreate сделать регистрацию

```
id := GlobalAddAtom('HotKey');
If not RegisterHotkey(Handle, id, 0, VK_SNAPSHOT) Then
     ShowMessage('Не получается зарегистрировать горячую клавишу');
```

В обработчике главной формы OnClose сделать отмену регистрации

```
UnRegisterHotkey(Handle, id);
GlobalDeleteAtom(id);
```

И добавить обработчик для сообщения WM_HOTKEY в форму

```
private
    Procedure WMHotkey(Var msg: TWMHotkey);
        message WM_HOTKEY;

    Procedure TForm1.WMHotkey(Var msg: TWMHotkey);
    Begin
        If msg.hotkey = 1 Then Begin
        // TODO: Делать то, что нужно
        End;
    End;
```

Comment: полный вид исходника можно, если не трудно?

Comment: даже не надо исходник, а вопрос куда вставлять приват? я заменяю со стандартным и вылетает ошибка в области     Procedure TForm1.WMHotkey(Var msg: TWMHotkey);